# French Numbering System - Eighty to Ninety-Nine

Tags: etymology, numbers

Why does French use the format "4 x 20 + n" (n = 0 to 19) for numbers from eighty to ninety-nine?

Comment: It's not so long ago that English speakers did something similar. Didn't some American guy once say something like "Four score and seven years ago...", meaning "87 years ago..."?

Comment: "c1720   M. Prior Daphne & Apollo 70   We mortals seldom live above fourscore." (OED)

Comment: Welsh also has a vigesimal system where 80 is _pedwar ugain_ (four-twenties) and 81 is _pedwar ugain ac un_ (four twenties and one). While it also has a, more commonly used, system similar to English where 80 can be _wythdeg_ (eigth tens) and 81 as _wythdeg un_ (eight tens + one).

Comment: Vigesimal counting is also used in Georgian and (I believe) Ainu.

Comment: linked: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/8943/5146

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The strange construction is a relic from a [vigesimal system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigesimal), i.e. a base 20 number system. This I'm just repeating from the Wikipedia page, but it seems it's thought to be of Basque origin.

The French construction is weird, but the Danish system is up there as well:

> 50 = halvtredsindstyve ( = half-3rd times 20 = 2½ times 20)
>   60 = tresindstyve ( = three times twenty)
>   70 = halvfjerdsindstyve ( = half-4th times 20 = 3½ times 20)
>   80 = firsindstyve (= four times twenty)
>   90 = halvfemsindstyve (= half-5th times 20 = 4½ times 20)

Note that these have more common short forms halvtreds, tres, halvfjerds, firs, halvfems. On top of the vigesimal thing, note the strange way to say 2½ (etc), half-3rd. As a bonus, Danish has the ones before the tens, e.g.

> 93 = treoghalvfemsindstyve (3 and half-5th(4½) times 20).

Comment: of Basque origin? Are you sure? Wikipedia says the Gauls had a vigesimal counting system!

Comment: @sergiol, I'm not sure it's of Basque origin. I'm sure that at the time I wrote this answer, the Wikipedia page listed it as one possibility. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vigesimal&oldid=484624224 Feel free to update the answer if you feel it's out-of-date.